# How to fill datagridview cells at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need my to fill my `datagridview` with values from some list. 
I try to make it in such way:

```
List<List<object>> objList1 = new List<List<object>>
    {
         new List<object> {null, null, null, "Some Value"},
         new List<object> {"Some text", "Another Text", 212}
    };

List<List<object>> objList2 = new List<List<object>>
    {
         new List<object> {null, null, null, "Some Value from 2 list"},
         new List<object> {"Some text 3", "Another Text 5", 34}
    };

foreach (var objList in objList1)
    {
         dataGridView.Rows.Add();
         for (int i = 0; i < objList.Count -1; i++)
         {
              dataGridView.Rows[dataGridView.RowCount - 1].Cells[i].Value = objList[i] != null ? objList[i].ToString() : "";
         }
    }
    dataGridView.Rows.Add();

foreach (var objList in objList2)
    {
         dataGridView.Rows.Add();
         for (int i = 0; i < objList.Count - 1; i++)
         {
             dataGridView.Rows[dataGridView.RowCount - 1].Cells[i].Value = objList[i] != null ? objList[i].ToString() : "";
         }
    }
    dataGridView.Rows.Add();
```

But instead of getting my `datagridview` filled, I get only the last row filled:

[image]

Comment: You should consider using `dataGridView.DataSource` instead of looping.

Comment: If adding *must* be done manually, consider using on of the Add forms that takes existing data, e.g.: `dataGridView.Rows.Add(objList.Select(o => (object)Convert.ToString(o)).ToArray())`. I *believe* the issue is caused by always editing the same row for some reason. If this is true, and avoided, the issue will naturally disappear.

Comment: But can I modify my code to make it works in proper way?

Comment: Consider using [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @user2246674 but how can it be same row?

Comment: @HnatiukDmitriy It was a hypothesis I presented (and I chose it because it would result in the observed behavior, even if I cannot see the "how"). You can run some tests to either prove or disprove the hypothesis: e.g. does changing to `Rows.Add(Object[])` make the issue go away?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But insted of get my datagridview filled I get only last row filled

You have `AllowUserToAddRow` property set to `true`. So when you when you write :

```
dataGridView.Rows[dataGridView.RowCount - 1]
```

you access to the *new row* that is "replaced" each time you add a new row. It should be instead

```
dataGridView.Rows[dataGridView.RowCount - 2]
```

Note that the `dataGridView.Rows.Add()` method give you the index of the added row. So you could also write:

```
int addedRowindex = DataGridView.Rows.Add();
DataGridView.Rows[addedRowindex].Cells[i].Value = ...
```

I am not sure to understand exactly what you are attempting to do. If I replace `RowCount - 1` with `RowCount - 2`, I get:

[image]

---

Also

```
for (int i = 0; i < objList.Count -1; i++)
```

should't be

```
for (int i = 0; i <= objList.Count - 1; i++)
```

Result:

[image]